# Android watch multiple EditText

Tags: java, android

I have a form in my android app with around 5 inputs. What I'd like to do is 'watch' all these inputs when focus is on them. What I'm thinking now is having the following code for each of the inputs but I think it'll be much of a hassle:

```
EditText tv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
                if (hasfocus) {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_border_focus);
                }
                else {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_border_nonfocus);
                }
            }
        });
```

So, is there any way to work around this problem, other than having to repeat the above code for each of the inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the `View.OnFocusChangeListener` interface on your class and then set the `setOnFocusChangeListener` as the class reference for all the `EditTexts`. Implement the `onFocusChange` method in class as below.

```
public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
      switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.password:
                 //Do your stuff here..
                 break;
            case R.id.editText2:
                 //Do your stuff here..
                 break;
      }
}
```

This way you don't need to repeat the code.